# Play audio streaming with MP3 files

Tags: audio-streaming, video.js, http-live-streaming

This is my scenario: 
I split mp3 file with FFmpeg with this command:

```
ffmpeg -i 1_1.mp3 -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k  -f
segment -segment_time 10 -segment_list outputlist.m3u8
-segment_format mp3 'output%03d.mp3'
```

I split the MP3 file base on time.
I have a total of 19 MP3 files that each one play 10 seconds and one outputlist.m3u8 file that contains a list of mp3 files. 
Now I want to have a webpage that gets outputlist.m3u8 file and play all MP3 files.
I used [Video.js](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls) script in my page with this configuration :

```
<video id=example-video width=600 height=300 class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls>
 <source
     src="https://example.com/index.m3u8"
     type="application/x-mpegURL">
</video>
<script src="video.js"></script>
<script src="videojs-contrib-hls.min.js"></script>
<script>
   var player = videojs('example-video');
   player.play();
</script>
```

I got this error in web console :

> video.js:24 VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED)
>   No compatible source was found for this video. 
>   t.J {code: 4, message: "No compatible source was found for this video."}

I also change type to "audio/mp3", "audio/mpeg"  and nothings changes.
I don't know what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

videojs-contrib-hls doesn't support mp3. See https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls/issues/1218

Comment: I convert all Mp3 files to Aac files with FFmpeg and update outputlist.m3u8 but Videojs give me the same error. I check with Vlc player and both mp3 and aac play very well with streaming. do you know any player that support  streaming mp3 files in web ?

Comment: adding the documentation link: https://github.com/videojs/http-streaming/blob/master/docs/supported-features.md